# Is there a way to use a list to manage and validate usernames and passwords in python

Tags: python

I am trying to design a login function that checks the username and password input. I want the program to break the while loop if the login details are correct and print the message in the `"login successful"`. But the while-loop does not break when the correct details are entered and fires the else-statement message first. Where am I going wrong?

I want it to check if the username and password stored in the `split_user_data` list match with user inputs and print 1`login successful"`  . Otherwise, I want to print `"Incorrect login details"`

Here's my code:

```
split_user_data = ['admin', ' adm1n']
def login():
    while True:
        username = input("Enter your username:").lower()
        password = input("Enter your password:").lower()
             
        for i in split_user_data:
               for j in split_user_data:
                if i == split_user_data[0] and j == split_user_data[1]:
                    print(" Login Successful.")
                    i = username
                    j = password
                    print(username)
                    print(password)
                    
                    break
                else:
                    print("Incorrect login details.")
                    continue
```

Comment: Please use consistent 4-space indentation. I can't tell if the `else:` is indented the same as `for` or `if`. It should be `for`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop over anything. Just check the username and password directly:

```
split_user_data = ['admin', 'adm1n']
def login():
    while True:
        username = input("Enter your username:").lower()
        password = input("Enter your password:").lower()
        if username == split_user_data[0] and password == split_user_data[1]:
            print("Login Successful.")
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect login details.")
            continue
login()
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. This solves the problems and makes the code work.